# kill function after specific time in php?

Tags: php, linux, function, timeout, exec

I have five `exec()` function in my script.I want if any function will not give any response in given time function will kill and then next function starts its execution.

```
 <?php

   exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);  
   exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/trun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);  
   exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/drun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);

 ?>
```

In this `timeout` argument not working.Please correct this or gives any alternative method.

Comment: `timeout` sends a `term` signal: If the process won't respondi to a term, you can send a `kill` signal instead using `timeout -k 5 /usr...`.

Comment: @MarkBaker I want kill command automatically send to server if `exec()` not respond in give time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash script caller.sh and execute it via exec. The command will be automatically killed after 5 seconds.

caller.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
sleep 5
kill $! 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

PHP

```
exec("caller.sh",$uptime);
```

Comment: sir,If function `exec()` execute before 5 sec then what will be the result ?

Comment: The command won't get killed and the execution finishes normally.You will get the O/P of command in $uptime variable.

Comment: sir, if function execute more then 5 sec then what will be return ?

Comment: Command will be killed at 5th second and return value will be `Killed command on time out`

Comment: Any method so command gives data, which it gets in first 5 second.

Comment: sir this script return data after 5 second.I think it will kill the `sleep` process not the `exec`.

Comment: sir please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777618/kill-command-in-linux

Comment: please help in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807051/can-we-use-php-in-bash-script/22807270?noredirect=1#22807270