# Kill Command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, command, sleep, kill

I have a **bash** script **abcd.sh**,in which I want to kill this command`(/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat')` after 5 sec but in this script it kill `sleep` command after 5 second.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
sleep 5
kill $! 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
pid=$!
sleep 5
kill $pid 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

**UPDATE:**

A working example (no special commands)

```
#!/bin/sh
set +x
ping -i 1 google.de &
pid=$!
echo $pid
sleep 5
echo $pid
kill $pid 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

Comment: +1 This solves the immediate issue in the shell script.  Using `timeout` is arguably a better option.

Comment: @drkunibar script not working,script runs command after 5 seconds

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. What command starts after 5 seconds? I have updated my answer with an example that should work on every system (changed your command with a `ping`)

Comment: @drkunibar `/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'` resume its working.After 5 sec it shows the `echo`  message and resume its working.

Comment: @Tomas Can your echo `pid` like it is in the example that we can see if `kill` calls the right `pid`. Maybe you need to call `kill -9 $pid`

Comment: @drkunibar yes `$pid` before and after the `sleep` are same.script stops command after 5 second and then print message and then resume the command again.

Comment: What is `wrun`? It seems to me, that `wrun` calls the commands insides the quotes. Have you tried `kill -9`? Can you check, that the process ID of `wrun` after the `kill` is the same than before? Maybe a service triggers `wrun` again if yout kill it.

Comment: @drkunibar if we use only `kill` command and skip `sleep` command the script kill the command `(/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat')` successfully if we use `sleep` then it resume command `(/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat')` after `kill` command

Comment: Are your shure you wrote `kill $pid` and not your old command `kill $!`?

Comment: @drkunibar please help in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807051/can-we-use-php-in-bash-script/22807270?noredirect=1#22807270

Answer (score 6):

You should use instead the [timeout(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command:

```
timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/wrun \
      'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'
```

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer for systems that ship with `timeout`. Sadly, `timeout` was only introduced in `coreutils 7` which means it's not available on e.g. `CentOS 5`.

Comment: neither on ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

Rather then try and construct your own mechanism why not make use of the `timeout` command.

#### Example

```
$ date; timeout 5 sleep 100; date
Tue Apr  1 03:19:56 EDT 2014
Tue Apr  1 03:20:01 EDT 2014
```

In the above you can see that `timeout` has terminated the `sleep 100` after only 5 seconds (aka. the duration).

#### Your example

```
$ timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/wrun \
    'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
sleep 5
pkill "wrun" && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variable `$!` contains the **PID of the most recent background command**. And this background command is in your case `sleep 5`. This should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
PID=$!
sleep 5
kill $PID 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```

Comment: Right, background command. Sleep is not being executed in the background.

Comment: @chaos script not working.script runs command after 5 seconds

Comment: What is `/usr/local/bin/wrun`? Is it this https://gist.github.com/orgoj/5326037 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat' &
PID=`ps -ef | grep /usr/local/bin/wrun | awk '{print $1}'`
sleep 5
kill $PID 2>/dev/null && echo "Killed command on time out"
```