# Can we use PHP in Bash Script?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a bash script `abcd.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 8`; do ssh w$i 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'; done &
pid=$!
sleep 1
kill -9 $pid
```

I want to use PHP in my bash script.

eg: in bash script I want to set value of `seq` through PHP.

Comment: yes, but have you ever tried?

Comment: Do you really want to set the number `seq` by php (looks stange) or do you want to get the number from a http server?

Comment: @drkunibar sir,this script gives data about server.Number of servers varies according to time so, I want to set `seq` value dynamically. `seq` value is equal to number of server.but I want when number of servers are change, script automatically calculate it and don't need to change in script again and again in script manually.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, if you are using bash, you should maybe use a bash shebang on line 1 so people know you are expecting bash features to be available. And if you are using bash, you can use a bash sequence anyway:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..8}; do echo $i; done
```

**Update 1**

If the number of servers is obtained through PHP, you can do something like this:

```
numservers=$(php -r 'echo 8;')
for i in $(seq $numservers); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

**Update 2**

Ok, you said the number of servers is dynamic, but then you say it is set in the script (which seems contradictory), but this is what you do:

```
numservers=10
for i in $(seq $numservers); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: sir,this script gives data about server.Number of servers varies according to time so, I want to set `seq` value dynamically.`seq` value is equal to number of server

Comment: can we use `foreach` loop in bash script ?

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can query number of servers using PHP.

Comment: if number of servers is 10 then will this script works properly

Comment: I assume you know how to get the number of servers using your own PHP, don't you? Put your code in inplace of my `echo 8` then it will work for your number of servers. How do you determine the number of servers?

Comment: @ Mark Setchell Is any method like `foreach loop` to calculate automatically number of result in bash script ?

Comment: You thoroughly confuse me. What is your real question? Why do you want to use PHP? What for? Why do you dislike using `seq`? What is wrong with your current script?

Comment: I want dynamically change in `seq` value according to number of server

Comment: Well, you said the number of servers is set manually in the script, so use the number you manually set.

Comment: but I want when number of servers are change, script automatically calculate it and don't need to change in script again and again.

Comment: Ok, so tell me how you can calculate the number of servers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005147/kill-and-sleep-command-not-working-properly-in-bash-script    please see this question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the entire shell script in PHP?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    exec("ssh w$i 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'");
}
?>
```

(code is untested, just an example)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand what you want.

Maybe this helps. The script defines a var `PHP_VAR` in bash and use this var in PHP. Then we call a PHP code snippet an put the output in the shell var `output`. At last we output the var `output` (but you can do something else with it).

**Attation:** All the output from the PHP will be found in the var `output`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I am a bash echo"

export PHP_VAR="I was in php"
# Here we start php and put the output in 'output'
output=$(php << EOF
   <?php \$inner_var = getenv("PHP_VAR");
   echo \$inner_var; ?>
EOF
)

# usage var 'output' with php output
echo "---$output---"
```