# Kill and Sleep command Not working properly in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sleep, kill

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do 
    ssh "w$i" 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'
done &
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill -9 $pid
```

I want to kill the `ssh` within the `for loop`, if it does not complete within 3 seconds. But my observations are, that the process is not killed and that the loop takes more than 3 seconds to kill.

Can you please help me to correct my script so my script can kill the `for loop` process after 3 seconds?

Comment: `want to kill the ssh` - Why then did you put `&` after done and not after sh? `done` must be on the last line and without `&`. Besides there there is a command `timeout` which handles this sort of task.

Comment: @skwllsp can you apply `timeout` command on my question ?

Comment: Could you try: `timeout 3 ssh .......`?

Comment: @skwllsp sir, is `timeout 3 ssh` kills complete `for loop` process or it kills process for specific number like for `$i=1` up to 10 ?

Comment: It kills (send SIGALRM) a command that is after it in the command line.

Comment: `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3` working...